# Hive Connection Error

Tags: hadoop, hive

I've been trying to install hive in hadoop and this error pops out, Does anybody have any idea what does this means?

[image: Hive connection]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is because you are using Hadoop3 which is still in second alpha test stage, simple solution is remove it and install hadoop2.7.3

Comment: I see, this means that the alpha version is not stable yet , am i right? thanks a lot for your answer.

Comment: Its not stable, alpha is a test version.

Answer (score 1):

The issue might be because of the incompatibility between your Hive version and the Hadoop version. Hadoop3 is very latest and Hive 0.12 is very old version. So you can either try upgrading your hive to any of the latest versions like Hive2.1.1 or you can try downgrading your Hadoop version to Hadoop2.x.

Comment: Thank you, I have already downgraded the hadoop, and it works,thank you for your response.